# Java exercise files without main?

Tags: java, program-entry-point

Been going through Core Java Fundamentals (Horstmann/Cornell) 9th edition, but sometime after chapter 5 or so both the exercise files and sample code stop having a "main" method but the book acts as if they should compile and run, etc...

Very confused since java apps need a main to run. Anyone familiar with these texts that can shed some light for me. Feeling pretty dumb right now :)

Comment: Perhaps the author has decided that by the time you get to chapter 5, you already recognise the need for a main method and they don't bother to repeat the same boilerplate code for each example?

Comment: I assumed the exercise files would be compilable, and they don't mention adding the boilerplate code to make it run. I assumed I was missing some concept about packages (i.e. maybe I should be running something else that accesses these package components, etc...)

Comment: Any reasonably useful application has more than one class. And you really should have only one main method residing in one of those classes. You do need at least one main method to run the application and invoke the different classes to accomplish your application's purpose. But beyond that your class does not need a main method to be used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Many libraries are developed without the purpose of running as a standalone application. [Joda-Time](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time) is one such example. It is a library you can use to simplify the manipulation of date and time data. Admittedly, the source repository I linked does have main methods in it, but that's because they are used in its unit tests.

The point of chapter five in Core Java Fundamentals is to introduce class inheritance, such that Vehicle can be superclass of Boat can be superclass of Sailboat can be superclass of Sunfish. The book probably has an example like Person > Employee > Manager, and eventually in that same chapter you may end up seeing a test class like TestManager that actually does have a main method using Manager.

Suppose I write a similar book and I show this over simplified version of the Person example. I create a project in Eclipse and I call it Personnel. I add a package `org.company` and inside that package I add these 3 classes:

**Person**

```
package org.company;
public class Person {
    public String name;
    public Person() {

    }
}
```

**Employee**

```
package org.company;
public class Employee extends Person {
    public String employeeID;
    public Employee() {

    }
}
```

**Manager**

```
package org.company;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class Manager extends Employee {
    public List<Employee> subordinates ;
    public Manager() {
        subordinates = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    }
}
```

I may now assume you can create your own project and incorporate these classes I've written. The fact I named mine *Personnel* is irrelevant. Call yours MyTest1, then don't even bother creating a package, and add one class called TestManager. As long as you A) put my classes two folders down in your project org / company / Person, Employee, Manager, or B) delete the `package org.company` from each of them and include them next to your new TestManager class, then you should be able to instantiate them in your test as:

**TestManager**

```
import org.company.Employee;
import org.company.Manager;
public class TestManager {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee bill = new Employee();
        bill.name = "Bill";
        bill.employeeID = "1";

        Employee george = new Employee();
        george.name = "George";
        george.employeeID = "3";

        Manager jill = new Manager();
        jill.name = "Jill";
        jill.employeeID = "1234";
        jill.subordinates.add(bill);
        jill.subordinates.add(george);

        //foreach
        for (Employee emp : jill.subordinates) {
            System.out.println(emp.name);
        }
    }
}
```

The files in Eclipse now look like this.

[image]

A future task for you to consider is to get a library from the internet such as Joda-Time and see about incorporating it into your project by adding it to the build path.

Comment: That helps a lot, but when I try to compile the 'Test' files I'll generate an error related to the other files in the package not being found. I've tried to set my classpath using export to include '.' but the other files in the package still won't compile or be found etc...

Comment: @JamesLingo My edit is extensive. It may shed some light on your situation. Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Starting to poke through this now, but I've been working without an IDE (using pico editor from command line) so that may just be part of my problem. Thanks a lot for being so thorough, gonna start working in Eclipse and let the IDE help me manage all the files :)

Comment: Just to confirm, the authors began coding in a simple command line editor but assume the readers have switched to IDE after packages get introduced. Running from inside Eclipse works great, although I'm still not sure what was wrong with my CLASSPATH variable, lol :).

Answer (score 1):

Classes will compile without main function but the problem comes when you want to execute the same class.

For Example:
Class A, Class B and Class B  having methods but not main method then you can invoke the program without main method. JVM need a ignition point to inform where to start. for the same example if Class A has main method where as other does not have . It fine to have like that  methods of class B and C can be invoked from Class A because JVM starts from A and executes other class method without trouble.